# What do you call the sets of window bars that are used to protect the window and are opened to the outside?

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

I was proofreading a translation and came across the sentence:

> The externally accessible windows are fitted with lockable, **outswing metal grids**.

What the translator meant really was this (on pictures) - two sets of metal bars that can be opened to the outside. They are secured on hinges and are used to protect the storage area (in my text).

What do we call them in English?

The Russian term is **распашные наружу металлические решетки** (metal bars that are opened to the outside).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Window [grille:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grille)***

> A grille is a framework of metal bars or wire which is placed in front of a window or a piece of machinery, in order to protect it or to protect people.

(Collins)

Answer (score 1):

They’re window security bars. The pictured ones are belly-style. They must be quick-open (without a key) to enable exit to the ground or a fire escape.

As pictured, they protect against entry frm the outside. Also called burglar bars.